# CSS problem with Elementor in wordpress (Linux distribution)

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I'm currently making my portfolio website with wordpress. I installed Elementor but the CSS does not work properly. I'm under Ubuntu 20.04, I follow the official ubuntu tutorial for installing wordpress.

***This is an example (I deleted previous pages, that I made before previsualisation)***

Elementor editor side:

[image]

Previsualisation:

[image]

Before posting this question here, I tried to solve my problem:

- Clear cache
- tested different browser (firefox, chrome, brave)
- added in wp-config.php:

  ```php
   define('FS_METHOD' , 'direct');
   define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false ); 
   define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );
  ```

I'm running out of ideas, and can't find suitable solutions to my case on internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you are addressing the CSS file correctly. How is it being called?

The url should be along the lines of `ht|tp://yoursite.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/yourtheme/style.css` you'll find somewhere that it's loading as `ht|tp://localhost/`and so it will load correctly on your machine but not on anyone else's.

Have a look in Developer Tools for the URL of style.css